# Run a function at midnight every day and delete records

Tags: asp.net, azure, backgroundworker, azure-webjobs

Im wanting to run a function every day at midnight. i've been looking but i think azure provides this service for you. Are webjobs the correct service to use? can i call my database to delete any records before the todays date?

I've seen Quartz but if azure provides this feature i dont see the point. thanks

Comment: Use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245975/quartz-net-setup-in-an-asp-net-website

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where your database is - is it on prem, an Azure SQL database or on a Azure VM?

If it is on prem or on a VM then a SQL Job might be the best option.

Otherwise, provided your web app can access the database, then a webjob would be a good option to use. You can schedule it using the built in sheduler on Azure or use a CRON expression. See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) for details on how to do these.

Answer (score 0):

To execute recurring jobs on a database, you can use an "Azure Function App" with a TimeTrigger function. You can find an example in the answers of this related question : 
[How to truncate SQL database on Microsoft Azure periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340522/how-to-truncate-sql-database-on-microsoft-azure-periodically/37598580#37598580)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to do complex scheduling, Quartz.net seems a bit like overkill to me.

Did you consider Azure automation? It gives you free retries, alerting, and a webhook URI for ad-hoc execution